# Storing time string into μ since epoch

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, calendar

I'm trying to convert a datetime.time string into an integer equal to total microseconds in python.

```
# my input
>>> mark_raw = '00:01:00.420000' # 0 hr, 1 min, 0 sec, 42 ms

# my desired output
>>> mark_time 
60420000
```

My current plan finds the difference between datetime since epoch, and date since epoch

```
# 0 hr, 1 min, 0 sec, 42 ms
>>> mark_raw = '00:01:00.420000'
>>> mark_dt = datetime.strptime(mark_raw, '%H:%M:%S.%f')

>>> mark_dt
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 420000)

>>> mark_date  = mark_dt.date()
>>> mark_date
datetime.date(1900, 1, 1)

>>> dt_epoch = calendar.timegm(mark_dt.timetuple()) * 1000
>>> dt_epoch
-2208988740000

>>> date_epoch = calendar.timegm(mark_date.timetuple())  * 1000
>>> date_epoch
-2208988800000

>>> mark_time = dt_epoch - date_epoch
>>> mark_time
60000
```

Not sure why I'm getting `60000` microseconds. Maybe a rounding issue?  I'm assuming `datetime.date(1900, 1, 1)` equals  `datetime.date(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)` but maybe that isnt the case.

The only requirement is getting the original time string to microseconds, open to any other strategies and any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the mismatch is,

```
>>> mark_dt.timetuple()
time.struct_time(tm_year=1900, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=0, tm_min=1, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1)
>>> mark_date.timetuple()
time.struct_time(tm_year=1900, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1)
```

You can see the difference here! `tm_min=1` in `mark_dt.timetuple()` and `tm_min=0` in `mark_date.timetuple()`

And,

```
dt_epoch = calendar.timegm(mark_dt.timetuple()) 
print dt_epoch

date_epoch = calendar.timegm(mark_date.timetuple())  
print date_epoch

mark_time = dt_epoch - date_epoch
print mark_time
```

will print

```
-2208988740
-2208988800
60
```

Thereby reflecting the tm_min = 1 and 0 difference in the two results!

**To get the microseconds**

And, if you want to get he microseconds, get the timedelta from epoch, find the total_seconds, and multiply that by 10^-6 that is 1e6

```
# 0 hr, 1 min, 0 sec, 42 ms
import datetime
import calendar
mark_raw = '00:01:00.420000'
mark_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(mark_raw, '%H:%M:%S.%f')

mark_date = mark_dt.date()
epoch_datetime=datetime.datetime(
    year=mark_date.year, 
    month=mark_date.month,
    day=mark_date.day,
)
print (mark_dt - epoch_datetime).total_seconds()*(1000000) 
#print (mark_dt - epoch_datetime).total_seconds()*ie6
```

**Output:**

```
60420000.0
```

hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `calendar.timegm` to `.timestamp()`:

```
>>> calendar.timegm(mark_dt.timetuple()) * 1000
-2208988740000
>>> mark_dt.timestamp() * 1000
-2208988739.58
```

The reason of the round problem in datetime is already explained by Keerthana answer.